# How to improve query performance in symfony for multiple relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Hi I am using symfony 2 for my application and using sg-datatable for displaying my data, now to feed the data table i used client side not server side and using this query:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Artist')
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id, c.name, c.sex, c.priority, c.bday, c.bmonth, c.byear')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    $cacsData = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.id, r.name as role, c.title as work')
        ->from('MyAppBundle:CastAndCrew', 'q')
        ->innerJoin('q.role', 'r')
        ->innerJoin('q.artists', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('q.content', 'c')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    $cacs = array();
    foreach ($cacsData as $cacData) {
        if (!array_key_exists($cacData['id'], $cacs)) {
            $cacs[$cacData['id']] = array();
        }
        $cacs[$cacData['id']][] = $cacData;
    }

    foreach ($entities as &$artist) {
        if (!array_key_exists($artist['id'], $cacs)) {
            continue;
        }

        $roles    = array();
        $contents = array();

        foreach ($cacs[$artist['id']] as $cac) {
            $roles[]    = $cac['role'];
            $contents[] = $cac['work'];
        }

        $artist['role']  = implode('/', array_unique($roles));
        $artist['works'] = implode('<br>', array_unique($contents));
    }

    $encoders    = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer  = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $datatable   = $this->get("bbd_datatables.artist");
    $datatable->setData($serializer->serialize($entities, "json"));

    return $this->render('MyAppBundle:Artist:index.html.twig', array(
       "datatable" => $datatable
    ));
}
```

everything is fine but the problem is query time, i have 20000+ data in my table and it's taking 250+ ms and because of the client side it paused few seconds then displays the data, can any one suggest me how i can improve the performance?

Comment: 1. Don't try sending 20000 records in one gulp. 2. Save your serialized data into artists.yml.  Tweak your controller to just load the artists.yaml file instead of the database query.  See how much of a difference this makes in page load time.  That will tell you which bottle neck to focus on.

Comment: How can i break them as there are filtering and searching option for the table?

Comment: Do paging. Also consider to cache the result.

Comment: @Cerad can you please give me an example of how to save my serialized data into artists.yml? Thanks a lot. Please also consider the fact that the data updates quite frequently.

Comment: file_put_contents($dataDir . '/SincTeamsReferees.yml', Symfony\Component\Yaml::dump($teams,10,2));